# How to delete a comment associated with a location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to delete a `comment` associated with a `location`.  These are my models:

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :location
end
```

**CommentsController.rb**

```
def destroy
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
  @comment = @location.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to locations_path
end
```

**comment.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', 
                location_comment_path 
                [comment.location, comment],
                method: :delete,
                class: "button",
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I expect a signed in user to delete their comment and be redirected to the location form, but it's not happening.

Instead, I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=1 [WHERE "comments"."location_id" = ?]): app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:21:in `destroy'

Comment: How're defined your routes?

Comment: My routes are nested:  resources :locations do
        resources :comments
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've setted the location and comment in your controller, then you can use them in the view.

Assuming the partial is being rendered through the index method, then:

```
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

def index
  @comments = Comment.all
  @location = Location.find params[:location_id]
end
```

Then in the partial, and passing both objects, you can access the route:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', 
  location_comment_path(@location, comment),
  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Note the use of parens and not square brackets.

If the comment to destroy has already been setted, then you don't need to worry about the location, just destroy the comment and redirect:

```
def destroy
  Comment.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to location_comments_path
end
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian!  Thanks for helping me out here! But after destroying the comment, I actually want to stay on the comment box page because the user might want to submit a new comment.  I don't want to redirect to the location's index page. Don't think it makes sense.  Sorry for the confusion.  Now what changes do I need to make to accomplish this?  if you need other info, pls let me know - Thanks! :)

Comment: So you can redirect to that specific path, `redirect_to location_comments_path`, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian!  Had to make other little changes, but it's working as expected!

Comment: Glad to help :)